# MYSQL Query - Issue running query with a null row value

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So I have been having trouble with this query.

```
SELECT 
    CR.rental_id AS 'RID',
    p1.rental_fee AS 'Guest Rental - RA',
    p1.clean_fee AS 'Guest Cleaning - RA',
    p1.tax AS ' Guest Taxes - RA',
    p1.damage_waiver AS 'Guest Damage Waiver - RA',
    p2.rental_fee AS 'PM Rental Fee',
    p2.clean_fee AS 'PM Cleaning Fee',
    p2.tax AS 'PM Tax',
    p2.damage_waiver 'PM Damage Waiver',
    p3.rental_fee AS 'Guest Rental - Channel',
    p3.clean_fee AS 'Guest Cleaning -  Channel',
    p3.tax AS 'Guest Taxes - Channel',
    p3.damage_waiver 'Guest Damage - Channel'



FROM
    backofficedb.core_rentals CR
         JOIN
    backofficedb.prices p1 ON CR.rental_id=p1.core_rental_id
         JOIN
    backofficedb.prices p2 ON CR.rental_id=p2.core_rental_id
         JOIN
    backofficedb.prices p3 ON CR.rental_id=p3.core_rental_id


WHERE 
    p1.type_vid=8 
    AND p2.type_vid=9 
    AND p3.type_vid=10
    AND CR.rental_id=x
```

Basically the issue is that the table will always have a VID 9 and 8, but not always have a VID 10.

The query works fine when all 3 VID records are present but breaks when VID 10 is null.

Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: try AND (p3.type_vid=10 or p3.type_vid is null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove condition from `where` clause and do a `left join` with additional clause `p3.type_vid=10`

```
SELECT ....
FROM ....
JOIN ....
LEFT JOIN backofficedb.prices p3 
ON CR.rental_id=p3.core_rental_id
AND p3.type_vid=10
WHERE 
    p1.type_vid=8 
    AND p2.type_vid=9
    AND CR.rental_id=x
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm not sure why I did not think of doing it that way.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I am not sure why I did not think of doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your p3 column I.e. p3.rental_fee AS 'Guest Rental - Channel'
Like  case when p3.rental_fee is null than 0 else p3.rental_fee
End case as  'Guest Rental - Channel'